# Using the Websocket Protocol

Tags: websocket, protocols, stability

An opinion question: do you think it's safe already to use WebSockets what with the changing protocols? If not, when do you reckon the protocols will be finished?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The protocol isn't really changing much any more. Most of the discussion is around optional extensions and phrasing in the specification. There was no wire protocol change between HyBi-08, 09 and 10 (which is why the handshake version has stayed at '8') and very little change between 08 and the previous several versions. The protocol has also completed last call and been referred to the IESG/IETF so radical changes are not likely unless some serious issue is discovered that throws the protocol back into the HyBi work group for rework.

One of the bigger changes coming soon is for in the HTML API related to binary data support and close events. However, these changes are basically just additive and still backwards compatible with the current API.